# How to place a textnode at the center of a drawn rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

A rectangle label does not appear inside the rectangle but on the corner of it.

```
  \tikzstyle{every node} = [align=center]
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2) node [center] {label}; 
     %center is unknown but was my best guess
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I move the labelling node to have a common center with the rectangle?

The result should look like this

```
  \tikzstyle{every node} = [align=center]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
    \node at (1,1) {label};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

but without having to specify the center manually.

Comment: Why not `\node[draw,rectangle, minimum size=2cm] at (1,1){label};`?

Comment: I had that approach before and i am now refactoring. I have trouble realigning my boxe´s if i dont explicitly state start and endpoints.

Comment: @Johannes: give a name to the node (e.g. `\node[draw,rectangle, minimum size=2cm] (name) at (1,1){label};`) then you will have `name.south west` for the lower left corner and `name.north east` for the upper right corner.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You should write instead:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[pos=.5] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By using `node` in a path without option, it will position the node to the last point.

[image: Image Description]

Comment: You can also use `[midway]` option instead of `[pos=.5]`. It is equivalent and the syntax sounds perhaps a bit more natural.

Answer (score 17):

You can write the Text, that should be centered, after the connection (rectangle in this case). It also works for lines etc.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Test} (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and `\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[pos=.5] {Test};` from Lionel's?

Comment: The result is the same, but the `pos` option is set implicitly.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that OP wants to draw a rectangle on fixed coordinates and later on insert the label in its center.

By default a `node` is a rectangle with a text in its center, so we could use it as an alternative.

Unfortunately node's solution needs some `minimum width|height|size` (which is not always respected) and it seems that OP doesn't want to compute them.

As an alternative `node` which does the work for us is a `fit` node. In this case we can enter both corner coordinates and insert the text with a `center` label. This solution has the advantage that we have created a correct size `node` which be used later on in our diagram.

```
\node[draw, fit={(0,0) (2,2)}, inner sep=0pt, label=center:Test] (A) {};
```

Rectangle corners can be absolute or relative coordinates. In this case we can use a `shift` option to place it where we want.

Following code shows both options, in blue Lionel or dexteritas solution and in black a `fit` node.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\node[draw, fit={(0,0) (2,2)}, inner sep=0pt, label=center:Test] (A) {};
\node[draw, fit={(0,0) (2,2)}, xshift=3cm, inner sep=0pt, label=center:Test] (B) {};
\draw (A)--(B);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[draw=blue, yshift=2.5cm]
\draw (0,0) rectangle node[draw] (A) {Test} ++(2,2); 
\draw (3,0) rectangle node[draw] (B) {Test} ++(2,2); 
\draw (A)--(B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]